# Click on Sprite only gets detected for the first Sprite (LibGDX)

Tags: kotlin, libgdx

Currently I'm working on a game like Mau-Mau (card game). The inner workings of the game do their job, just like they should. But for some reason when the player is able to lay several cards the game only detects a mouse click on the first card which can be layed. The mouse clicks are detected like this:

```
private var screenX = -1
private var screenY = -1

override fun touchUp(screenX: Int, screenY: Int, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
        if (button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) {
            this.screenX = screenX
            this.screenY = screenY
        }
        return false
    }

fun isCardClicked(card: Card): Boolean {
        if (card.getSprite().boundingRectangle.contains(screenX.toFloat(), (Gdx.graphics.height - screenY).toFloat())) {
            screenX = -1
            screenY = -1
            return true
        }
        screenX = -1
        screenY = -1
        return false
    }
```

The method `isCardClicked()` is called in my `Game` class:

```
while (cardIterator.hasNext() && !cardLayed) {
        val card = cardIterator.next()
        if (player.isPlayable(card, deliCard)) {
                if (inputHandler.isCardClicked(card)) {
                        println("player: $card")
                        deliStack.take(card)
                        cardIterator.remove()
                        cardLayed = true
                        changeTurns()
                }
        }
}
```

Does anybody know why I'm only able to lay the first layable card but not every other layable card in the player hand?

Comment: It's been 8 years since I worked with LibGDX, but this might not be related to it. I'm not sure what screenX and screenY are, but they seem to be some global variables that get set to -1 in you isCardClicked() method. Are they ever changed back to something else?

Comment: Accidently posted a wrong piece of code for isCardClicked(). I updated the piece to the latest version and swaped keyDown() (which doesn't matter in this case) with touchUp(). It should now be understandable what is happening.

Comment: If you are using a camera, you might need to unproject the coordinates like explained [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/117901/143689).

Comment: I'm not using any camera right now.

Comment: I would highly recommend putting the camera in ASAP, as it will get exponentially harder to add it as your development progresses. There will be more and more potential subtle bugs arising from certain places in your code where you forget to add the use of the camera. And you will waste time having to figure out a bunch of unnecessary math (like your Y flipping above) as you develop without the camera.

Comment: I just added a camera to my game and changed a few things so that everything works like without the camera. But unfortunately I'm still only able to click on one of the layable cards, so the problem isn't fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    fun isCardClicked(card: Card): Boolean {
        screenX = -1
        screenY = -1
        return card.getSprite().boundingRectangle.contains(screenX.toFloat(), (Gdx.graphics.height - screenY).toFloat())
    }
```

You're resetting `screenX` and `screenY` to -1 before checking *any* card. So only the card overlapping that point will ever return true, not the card under the click point.

And a side note...with Kotlin you don't have to manually use the iterator to be able to find and remove an item. Your loop could be replaced with:

```
val removedCard = cardList.removeFirstOrNull { card ->
    player.isPlayable(card, deliCard) && inputHandler.isCardClicked(card)
}
if (removedCard != null) {
    println("player: $card")
    deliStack.take(card)
    changeTurns()
}
```

Comment: Changed the code as shown above now but it's still not working

Comment: Is `player.isPlayable(card, deliCard)` returning true for the other cards?

Comment: Nope it isn't but the coordinates stored in `screenX` and `screenY` are in the BoundingRectangle of these cards.

Comment: Your loop is filtering out cards that aren't playable. And why does the `isCardClicked()` function reset where the screen was clicked at all?

Comment: Just because otherwise this position will still be stored in screenX und screenY. Actually all cards that are playable are highlighted and I manually checked them to be playable so only playable Cards will be filtered.

Comment: For some reason I also can't use the removeFirstOrNull method. For storing the cards of one hand I am using a MutableList and this list gets initialized with mutableListOf<Card>().